# How can I implement logrotate for the below condition?

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I have specific set of logs for different process. Consider

Log_name1.Date.0.log (oldest on the current Date)-----> 
Log_name1.Date.1.log
Log_name1.Date.2.log

Log_name2.Date.0.log (oldest on the current Date)-----> 
Log_name2.Date.1.log
Log_name2.Date.2.log

Like these, the logs  will be added every day. Now I wish to implement logrotate like this that, all the logs for a specific date should be zipped together after 3 days. i.e.. If today logs were stored, after 3 days, it must be zipped automatically. all the different logs can be zipped together. but each day must have separate tar.gz. Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure OS, but you can make a Cron or Program task with an script; this is an example of script on linux:

```
#! /bin/sh
tipo=${PWD##*/} 
bkp_dir="/home/USER/${tipo}-$(date +%Y%m%d)"
echo "BackUp From Folder: ${tipo}"
echo "Make BackUpFolder: ${bkp_dir}"
mkdir $bkp_dir
for dir in */
do
    base=$(basename "$dir")
    tar -zcvf "${bkp_dir}/${base}-$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz" "$dir/Log_name1.*.log"
done
sleep 5
clear
echo "BackUp Ready:"
ls -l $bkp_dir
```